# Mongoexport throwing too many positional arguments error on --query parameter

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a request I run using with the mongoshell and working perfectly fine :

```
db.projects.find({ProductRange: { $in : ['BUILDING_INSURANCE', 'CONSTRUCTION_INSURANCE', 'RC_INSURANCE', 'DAB_INSURANCE', 'PFI_INSURANCE']}})
```

I want to run a `mongoexport` command in order to extract the data matching this query. Here is the commandline :

```
mongoexport --uri="mongodb://user:foooo@fooooo:27017,foooo2:27017,foooo3:27017/foooDb?replicaSet=foooRS" --collection=projects --out=foooo.json --query='{'ProductRange': { $in : ['BUILDING_INSURANCE', 'CONSTRUCTION_INSURANCE', 'RC_INSURANCE', 'DAB_INSURANCE', 'PFI_INSURANCE']}}'
```

I get the following error :

> error parsing command line options: too many positional arguments: [{
>   $in : ['BUILDING_INSURANCE', 'CONSTRUCTION_INSURANCE', 'RC_INSURANCE',
>   'DAB_INSURANCE', 'PFI_INSURANCE']}}']

Using the folowing query give me another issue :

```
mongoexport --uri="mongodb://user:foooo@fooooo:27017,foooo2:27017,foooo3:27017/foooDb?replicaSet=foooRS" --collection=projects --out=foooo.json --query='{ProductRange:BUILDING_INSURANCE}'
```

> query '[123 80 114 111 100 117 99 116 82 97 110 103 101 58 66 85 73 76
>   68 73 78 71 95 73 78 83 85 82  65 78 67 69 125]' is not valid JSON:
>   invalid character 'U' in literal BinData or Boolean (expecting 'i' or
>   'o')

Comment: try query parameter with double quotes `--query="somequery"`

Comment: `--query='{"ProductRange": { $in : ["BUILDING_INSURANCE", "CONSTRUCTION_INSURANCE", "RC_INSURANCE", "DAB_INSURANCE", "PFI_INSURANCE"]}}'` doesn't work either

Comment: --query="{'ProductRange': { $in : ['BUILDING_INSURANCE', 'CONSTRUCTION_INSURANCE', 'RC_INSURANCE', 'DAB_INSURANCE', 'PFI_INSURANCE']}}"

Comment: @ZavenZareyan `Failed: error parsing query as Extended JSON: invalid JSON input`

Comment: so try without quotes --query={ProductRange: { $in : ['BUILDING_INSURANCE', 'CONSTRUCTION_INSURANCE', 'RC_INSURANCE', 'DAB_INSURANCE', 'PFI_INSURANCE']}}

Comment: nice try @ZavenZareyan but I have the same issue : `error parsing command line options: too many positional arguments: [{ $in : ['BUILDING_INSURANCE', '
CONSTRUCTION_INSURANCE', 'RC_INSURANCE', 'DAB_INSURANCE', 'PFI_INSURANCE']}}]`

Comment: What I'm saying is there's syntax issue with quotes or other characters, so you need to find this.

Comment: @ZavenZareyan you're right let me take 10 mns and trying to figure it out.

Comment: If I put `--query="{ProductRange:BUILDING_INSURANCE}"` I have the following error message : `query '[123 80 114 111 100 117 99 116 82 97 110 103 101 58 66 85 73 76 68 73 78 71 95 73 78 83 85 82
 65 78 67 69 125]' is not valid JSON: invalid character 'U' in literal BinData or Boolean (expecting 'i' or 'o')`

Comment: And if I put ` --query='{ProductRange:BUILDING_INSURANCE}'` I have the following error message : `query '[39 123 80 114 111 100 117 99 116 82 97 110 103 101 58 66 85 73 76 68 73 78 71 95 73 78 83 85
 82 65 78 67 69 125 39]' is not valid JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type map[string]interface {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and got it to work after reading the query needs to be expressed in a [strict JSON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/reference/mongodb-extended-json/): that is all attributes must be enclosed in double quotes.

On Windows I entered my query as:

```
-q "{ \"createdOn\": { \"$gt\": { \"$date\": \"2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z\" } } }"
```

I hope that helps.